# Does orca rrdtool apply any averaging/fudging of graph values?

Tags: performance, monitoring, solaris-10

I have a plot of data that consists solely of zero and one values. However, the orca plot that results shows intermediate values.

I wonder why this is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is [Orca](https://www.orcaware.com/orca/docs/orca.html), your collector and plot settings dictate how data will be represented on the graph. By default, you'll probably see 5-minute value averages at this scale.

Comment: ah. That's interesting. Is there a way to remove the averaging?

Comment: How often are YOU collecting the data? You'll have to tweak your orcallator.cfg to match.

Comment: The best resource is Orcaware: https://www.orcaware.com/contact.html

Comment: frequency of collection is 5 minutes. I don't see a plot setting in orcallator.cfg though to tweak and match.

Comment: The closest I can see is interval in group config. That is now set to 300 for me.